# Word that means 'saying something as though it's obvious'?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning

I'm new here. Nice to meet everyone.

I'm a writer and my quest to find the appropriate word led me here. Specifically, I'm trying to find a word to describe the way someone utters a phrase.

Saying "She says it like it's obvious.", "She says it like it's evident." or any variation seems to be far too clunky versus just using an adjective that means that. 
Is there such an adjective? Thank you.

Comment: IMHO, there is no single word to express "as if it is obvious"

Comment: How about "naturally"? I searched adverb for "take for granted" and "naturally" was one of the results.

Comment: Condescendingly?

Comment: Are you looking for an adjective with a negative connotation?

Comment: If you were writing on Twitter, you might have said something like “she duh’ed at him”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to try the adverb ***matter-of-factly***.

Wiktionary:

> *Adverb*
>   **[matter-of-factly](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/matter-of-factly)** ‎(not comparable)
>
> As though stating a fact.
>
> As though the situation is normal and not unusual; not dramatically or
>   fancifully.

M-W:

> **[matter-of-factly](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/matter-of-factly)**
>   *adverb*
>
> :  without showing emotion especially when talking about exciting or
>   upsetting things : *She explained the problem **matter-of-factly**.*

Comment: That doesn't really imply any kind of obviousness, just simplicity and lack of bravado.

Comment: I thought `as though stating a fact` can be taken as an approximation of `saying as though it is obvious`.

Comment: That has a nice kick, yet, only usually says or means unusual callously handing, out facts. Is there an adverb like it that maybe is a more formal way of saying "Duh!"?

Answer (score 1):

I've been thinking about this myself, and I think depending on the context you could use, "she scoffed"; it's not exactly the same thing, but I think it can work in a lot of situations, i.e. "'Of course I'm not lying,' she scoffed."

Cambridge gives:

> [scoff](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/scoff?q=Scoff) verb (LAUGH)
>
> to laugh and talk about a person or idea in a way that shows that you
> think they are stupid or silly:
> The critics scoffed at his painting.
>
> to speak about someone or something in a way which shows that you have
> no respect for that person or thing:
> The coach scoffed at the notion
> that he was about to resign.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi @guest writer, welcome to EL&U.  I added the definition for you and encourage you to see the [help] and take the site [tour].  You can always [edit] to give more information about how this answers the question.